# FastApi NGINX gunicorn проблема при использовании сокета

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, fastapi

**/etc/systemd/system/fastAPI.service:**

```
[Unit]

Description=Gunicorn Daemon for FastAPI Demo Application

After=network.target



[Service]

User=root

Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/xomic/fastAPI

ExecStart=/home/xomic/fastAPI/venv/bin/gunicorn app:app --workers 2 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind unix:appname.sock



[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**sudo systemctl status fastAPI:**
[image: sudo systemctl status fastAPI]

```
(venv) xomic@vm146039:~/fastAPI$ sudo curl --unix-socket unix:/home/xomic/fastAPI/appname.sock localhost
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Собственно не могу понять почему не работает.
Задача развернуть FastApi Python, на уже готовый NGINX SSL сервер.
Пробовал по этому гайду: [ССЫЛКА](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-deploy-fastapi-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

Спасибо!

Код заглушка:
При запуске не через  сервис все работает, но чтоб прикрутить к серверу нужен сервис, как я понял.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def home():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Comment: какие права у файла /home/xomic/fastAPI/appname.sock ?

Comment: 777, группа www-data